# Unsure why my code is spitting out an empty set

Tags: python, csv

new programmer here. So in the code I have below, the "year1" set works just like it is supposed to and spits out a set of years back at me. Although when I try to do the same thing for the "year2" set the only thing it spits back out at me is "set()".

I was wondering what is going on in the code that is making this so? Thanks for any help in advance!

```
def compare(word1, word2, startDate, endDate):
    with open('all_words.csv') as allWords:
        readWords = csv.reader(allWords, delimiter=',')
        year1 = set()
        for row in readWords:
            if int(startDate) <= int(row[1]) < int(endDate):
                if row[0] == word1:
                    year1.add(row[1])
        year2 = set()
        for row in readWords:
            if int(startDate) <= int(row[1]) < int(endDate):
                if row[0] == word2:
                    year2.add(row[1])
```

Comment: Your `if` statements seem weird. Are you sure you want that? You are converting a `Bool` to `int`, this is, a `0` or `1`.

Comment: Add `print(row)` in your second `for row in readWords` loop. I think `readWords` is consumed once it is iterated through once, in which case nothing will print to confirm it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned, you cannot iterate over the file twice without *resetting* it.  You have duplicate code in your process - you could factor out the duplications and just iterate once.

```
def compare(word1, word2, startDate, endDate):
    with open('all_words.csv') as allWords:
        readWords = csv.reader(allWords, delimiter=',')
        year1 = set()
        year2 = set()
        for row in readWords:
            if int(startDate) <= int(row[1]) < int(endDate):
                if row[0] == word1:
                    year1.add(row[1])
                if row[0] == word2:
                    year2.add(row[1])
```

Answer (score 2):

At the point, you create `year2` you have already read whole file (you are at the end of it). So you should `seek()` to the start of the file to go through it again. So:

```
....
allWords.seek(0)
year2 = set()
....
```